# pthread_spin_lock not working

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I have following piece of code :

// temp.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_spinlock_t mylock;

__attribute__((constructor))
void init_lock() {
   if(pthread_spin_init(&my_lock,0) != 0) {
      // hard exit !!
      exit(1);
   }
}

__attribute__((destructor))
void uninit_lock() {
   if(pthread_spin_destroy(&my_lock) != 0) {
      // hard exit !!
      exit(1);
   }
}

#define EXPAND_VAR(ARG1, ARG2) \
   do {\
      assert(pthread_spin_lock(&my_lock) == 0);
       /// do something
      assert(pthread_spin_unlock(&my_lock) == 0);\
    }while(0)
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "temp.h"
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *logs(void *i){
   int j;
   for(j = 0 ; j < 10000 ; j++){
      EXPAND_VAR(j, j+1);
   }
    std::cout << "returning from thread func" << std::endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int i;
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

   for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        std::cout << " creating threads" << std::endl;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,logs,(void *)i);
   }

   std::cout << "returning from main" << std::endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

When executing the above code 'pthread_spin_lock' always gets blocked. I tried 'pthread_spin_trylock' and it passes with return value 0.

Anything i am missing that 'pthread_spin_lock' not working ?

I am using gcc version 4.1.2 :(

Comment: There isn't a call to `init_lock`....

Comment: @LPs : its called during initialization. '__attribute__((constructor))' handles this.